# Clojure - Get Realtime Updates with Cloud Firestore

Tags: clojure, google-cloud-firestore

Here is EventListener interface

```
package com.google.cloud.firestore;

    public interface EventListener <T> {
      void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable T t, @javax.annotation.Nullable com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException e);
    }
```

Here is the Java section code
   (refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
    docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
      @Override
      public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                          @Nullable FirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
          System.err.println("Listen failed: " + e);
          return;
        }

        if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
          System.out.println("Current data: " + snapshot.getData());
        } else {
          System.out.print("Current data: null");
        }
      }
    });
```

Here is my converted code to Clojure

```
(defn outlook-synced-listenning
      [^DocumentReference ref]
      (let []
        (-> ref
            (.addSnapshotListener
              (reify EventListener
                (^void onEvent [this ^DocumentSnapshot  snapshot ^FirestoreException e]

                  (if-not (nil? e)
                    (println " Listen failed: " + e)
                    )
                  (if (and (not (nil? snapshot)) (.exists snapshot))
                    (println " Current data: " + (.getData snapshot))
                    (println " Current data null ")
                    )

                )))
            )
        ))
```

Here is the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find matching method: onEvent, leave off hints for auto match.
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$NewInstanceMethod.parse(Compiler.java:8305)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$NewInstanceExpr.build(Compiler.java:7853)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$NewInstanceExpr$ReifyParser.parse(Compiler.java:7754)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6919)
```

I think the error with parameter types and type hints when the Clojure code does not match with Java interface.

I guess that I don't still convert correctly the code line below to Clojure
    docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener < DocumentSnapshot > ()

Please advise me how I do. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I removed all paramater types and type hints except for "this". It works fine

Many thanks to Frank Moyer

```
(defn outlook-synced-listenning
      [^DocumentReference ref]
      (let []
        (-> ref
            (.addSnapshotListener
              (reify EventListener
                (onEvent [this snapshot e]

                  (if-not (nil? e)
                    (println " Listen failed: " + e)
                    )
                  (if (and (not (nil? snapshot)) (.exists snapshot))
                    (println " Current data: " + (.getData snapshot))
                    (println " Current data null ")
                    )

                )))
            )
        ))
```